# Receiving events in the service from firebase

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular7

I have a full calender installed in my componenten. Now i try to receive events what are saved in Firebase. for that i created the service events. When i declare the objects manualy everything works fine but when i try to receive those data from firebase i get an error, maybe there is something i don't see. Thanks for your help.

The error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at SafeSubscriber._next

My events service:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {

    eventsRef: AngularFireList<any>; 
    events$: Observable<any[]>;


    constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase){}

    public getEvents(): Observable<any> {
        const dateObj = new Date();
        const yearMonth = dateObj.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1);
        //Declaration of the array with events
        let data: any = [];

        //Receiving all events from the firebase table and pushing them to the array
        this.eventsRef = this.db.list('/events');
        this.events$ = this.eventsRef.valueChanges();
        this.events$.subscribe(events=> data.push(events));

        console.log(data);
        //Return the array to the component to render the events
        return Observable.of(data);
    }
};
```

My component:

```
import { MatDialog, MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarComponent } from 'ng-fullcalendar';
import { Options } from 'fullcalendar';
import { EventService } from '../event.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AddEventDialogComponent } from '../add-event-dialog/add-event-dialog.component';
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import resourceDayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-daygrid';
import { Duration } from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agenda',
  templateUrl: './agenda.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agenda.component.css']
})
export class AgendaComponent implements OnInit {
  calendarOptions: Options;
  Duration: Duration;
  displayEvent: any;
   @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) ucCalendar: CalendarComponent;
   constructor(protected eventService: EventService, public dialog: MatDialog, public router: Router, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

   calendarEl

   ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(data => {

      console.log(data[0].id);
      this.calendarOptions = {
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: false,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        events: data.filter( ev => ev.id == '999'),
        nowIndicator: true,
        slotDuration: '00:10',
        locale: 'nl',
        //minTime: '08:30:00',
        //maxTime: '23:00:00',
        //titleFormat: 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY'
      }

    });

   }
   clickButton(model: any) {
     this.displayEvent = model;
   }
   eventClick(model: any) {
     model = {
       event: {
         id: model.event.id,
         start: model.event.start,
         end: model.event.end,
         title: model.event.title,
         allDay: model.event.allDay
         // other params
       },
       duration: {}
     }
     this.displayEvent = model;
   }
   updateEvent(model: any) {
     model = {
       event: {
         id: model.event.id,
         start: model.event.start,
         end: model.event.end,
         title: model.event.title
         // other params
       },
       duration: {
         _data: model.duration._data
       }
     }
     this.displayEvent = model;
   }

   addEvent(){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddEventDialogComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: {},
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

      console.log(result);

    });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback passed to `subscribe` in `this.events$.subscribe(events=> data.push(events));` gets executed **asynchronously** which means that in the moment of returning `data` won't be populated i.e. it will be still just an empty array. To fix this just return `this.events$`:

```
public getEvents(): Observable<any> {
        const dateObj = new Date();
        const yearMonth = dateObj.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1);
        //Declaration of the array with events
        let data: any = [];

        //Receiving all events from the firebase table and pushing them to the array
        this.eventsRef = this.db.list('/events');
        this.events$ = this.eventsRef.valueChanges();
        return this.events$;
}
```